# Output a GridView to Excel outside of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, httpcontext

I want to have a helper class that can serve requests from multiple pages to output contents of any gridview to excel. But if I pass in the GridView it throws an error that it must be inside "form runat='server'" tags, which makes sense. However is there anyway to do this in a seperate class that is not directly connected to any particular page?

Here is the code:

```
  public class Export 
{
    public static void ToExcel(GridView control, params string[] headers)
    {
        HttpResponse context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response; 

        context.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
        context.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        context.Charset = "";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<img src='C:\\logo.png'/>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<B>");
        stringWriter.WriteLine("Usage Report:  ");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("</B>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<table>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<tr>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<td colspan=4 bgcolor=Gainsboro align=center>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<B>");

        foreach (string str in headers)
        {
            stringWriter.Write(str);
            stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("<br />");
        }

        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("</B>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("</td>");
        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("</tr>");

        control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

        stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().Append("</table>");
        context.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        context.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may have this problem the solution is to add this overrided method to the page that the GridView is coming from:

```
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        return;
    }
```